# I'm on a debugger mode and I can't fix org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError and WARNING: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

It's my first post here. I know everyone's been getting this error eversince the Google Chrome update. I'm a beginner in programming and here are my dependenceis

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.rcv</groupId>
    <artifactId>SeleniumTraining</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And here are the initial code lines:

```
    String report = "Report of Anna's DemoAutomation:";

    static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd HH:mm");
    String now = formatter.format(ZonedDateTime.now());
    static ChromeOptions options;
    static WebDriver driver;

    static String variablesHere = "variablesHere";

    public void setUp() {
        
        options = new ChromeOptions().setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9014");
        options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        report(report);
        report("Time started: " + now + "\n");

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\Anna\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://google.com");
```

So I've tried to use the other solutions I found on the internet such as adding options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*") and also did try to add the dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-http-jdk-client</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and set the system property to

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "jdk-http-client");
```

But both solutions didn't work and I am still getting the errors. What a nightmare. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have `WebDriverManager` dependency, but not using it in code, you can try something like:

`WebDriverManager.chromedriver().capabilities(<chrome-options-here>).create()`,

Also, if you do place chromedriver.exe manually, you should set system property `webdriver.chrome.driver` **before** instantiating ChromeDriver()

In both of these cases the error should differ from the above though

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me after I have installed new version : Version: 118.0.5993.70 (r1192594) chrome driver from link : https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path...\\chromedriver.exe");

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: This argument allows web pages to make cross-origin requests to a WebDriver server. By specifying *, it effectively allows requests from any origin. This is useful in scenarios where your web application needs to interact with a WebDriver server from different origins or domains. Without this option, the same-origin policy enforced by web browsers might block such requests.